# TCP socket close behavior on fork

Tags: c, sockets, tcp, fork

First, let me describe what i am trying to accomplish.

I have a Server that i am trying to test via automatic testing. For this purpose, the server is instrumented during compilation with a forkserver routine that can be triggered to interrupt the normal control flow and enter a forking loop (Similar to the one AFL++ uses).
This works as expected.

The server uses TCP to communicate. Initially the testing program will send a few inputs to the server and then enter the forking mode, in order to continue on from this "snapshot".
This works for the first time the program is forked.
The forked process is killed or exits normally. Afterwards a new process is forked from the original.

From reading the close man page i would have expected the tcp socket to still be able to receive data, since it was only closed in the child process, and not in the parent process.
But this is not the case, since the next send to the server fails with `errno=32`.

I now have two questions regarding this:

1. Have i misunderstood the way tcp sockets are handled on forking?
2. If the above approach (forking, and continuing to use the same tcp connection) does not work, what could be an alternative to achieve the desired effect, of continuing from a specific execution point with the same tcp connection as before?

Comment: You understand the documentation well. OS close the socket only if it is closed in all processes. I think there must be something else wrong with your program. Forking and continuing an existing TCP connection can cause problem if you call read in both processes. Then it is hard to predict what process gets the received data. OS may chose any process that is sleeping in the read.

Answer (score 0):

[link to the send error](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/send.2.html#ERRORS)

1. The `EPIPE` (errno=32) error show that the local end has been shut down. So the parent socket not closed. However the TCP connection may shutdown.
2. I suggest to use one socket for each process by using an array. But this solution looks a bit nag.

Comment: I cannot change the behavior of the target, since it is being tested. I guess an alternative would be to use some kind of virtualization but the overhead of that would likely outweigh the benefits of snapshots in the first place.
Also, the epipe error occurs on the sending side (i.e. the testing software). The server (i.e. the software under test) is the one being forked. A close in the forked child should not impact the socket in the parent if i understood the manpages correctly.